# Applying a polynomial to an operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T \in L(V)$ and $\exists$ a positive integer n such that $T^n = 0$. Prove that $(I-T)$ is invertible and that $(I-T)^{-1} = I + T + \dots + T^{n-1}$.

I wish I could say that I attempted something for this problem but I don't even know how to start except to show that $(I - T)$ is injective and surjective, and for the second part I have absolutely no idea, can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried multiplying $I - T$ times $I+T+...+T^{n-1}$?

Comment: Yeah I just realized how easy that is, but is that sufficient to show that T $(I - T)$ is invertible?

Answer (score 2):

$(I-T)(I+T+\ldots+T^{n-1})= I+T+\ldots+T^{n-1} - T -\ldots -T^n = I - T^n =I$, and similarly
$(I+T+\ldots+T^{n-1})(I-T)=I$.

Therefore $(I-T)^{-1} = I + T + \dots + T^{n-1}$ and, of course, then $I-T$ is invertible, since we are explicitly exhibiting its inverse.

Answer (score 1):

$(I-T)(I+T+\ldots+T^{n-1})=(I+T+\ldots+T^{n-1})(I-T)=I$

Comment: shoot yeah of course sorry! but how would I prove that it's invertible? Is this sufficient?

Comment: $I-T$ is invertible iff there exists $S$ such that $(I-T)S=S(I-T)=I$

Comment: Thank you this makes alot more sense!